# SQL Query on finding the max occurences of an element

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query, in order to find the element appearing most number of times. But, if the occurrences of multiple element is same, it shouldn't find anything. The output should be empty. My query is successful in finding if there is only 1 element coming up, but if we have two or more than two elements occurring most number of times, still it is calculating the value.

For example,
16,16,21,21,23,25,31,31

In this, Since 16,21 and 31 all occurs twice, it should not calculate any value. But my query is calculating 31 as the Value occurring most number of times

For example,
15,16,21,21
--For this the query is calculating correctly, the output as 21.

```
select *,tt.V1 as "FINAL"
from table t left join
(select t.*
from
(select "Value" as "V1", "Group" as "CL1",count(*) as "Count of Max Occurence",row_number() over (partition by "Group" order by count(*) desc ) as "dummy" from table 
group by "Value","Group"
having count(*)>1
)t
where "dummy" =1
)tt
on tt."CL1"=t."Group"
```

How can I modify my code to get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

You aggregation and window functions.  In this case, count the number of aggregated rows with the same count and then use that for filtering as well:

```
select x.*
from (select "Value" as V1, "Group" as CL1,
             count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by "Group" order by count(*) desc ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by "Group", count(*)) as cnt_cnt
      from table 
      group by "Value", "Group"
     ) x
where cnt_cnt = 1 and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: How are we adding count(*) over (partition by cnt) as cnt_cnt?  It will show Invalid Column right?

Comment: @Ayn76 . . . Some wishful coding there.  That should be `partition by count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

*First* simple calculate the count per *group* and the *value*.

*Second* calculate the next count in the same *group* `lead_cnt` and
the order (`rn`) of the value withing *group* ordered on `cnt` descending.

Select only values the have the first rank (`rn = 1`) but the `lead_cnt` differes from the `cnt`of the row.

Query

```
with cnt as (
select grp, v1, count(*) cnt
from t
group by grp, v1),
cnt2 as (
select 
 grp,v1, 
 cnt,
 lead(cnt) over (partition by grp order by cnt desc) lead_cnt,
 row_number() over (partition by grp order by cnt desc) rn
from cnt
)
select grp, v1 from cnt2
where 
  rn = 1 and cnt != IFNULL(lead_cnt,0)
```

Result for the samle data below

```
       GRP         V1
---------- ----------
         1         16

create table t as
select 1 grp, 16 v1 from dual union all
select 1 grp,16 v1 from dual union all
select 1 grp,16 v1 from dual union all
select 1 grp,21 v1 from dual union all
select 1 grp,21 v1 from dual union all
select 2 grp,25 v1 from dual union all
select 2 grp,25 v1 from dual union all
select 2 grp,31 v1 from dual union all
select 2 grp,31 v1 from dual;
```

Comment: But if we have values: 31,31,31. In this case too, the answer should be nothing, since we cannot determine. I tried testing your query, it returns 31 as the answer.

Comment: @Ayn76 *please*  provide **complete** sample data and expected output. *What* you can't determine if there is *only one number* in a group?

Comment: So there should be a miniumum of 2 values in order to compare the frequency of an element

Comment: Than simple replace `cnt != IFNULL(lead_cnt,0)` with `cnt != lead_cnt` this will return result only when `lead_cnt` (the count of the second value) is `not null`. @Ayn76